# как в данном примере обернуть элемент div с помощью js

Tags: javascript

**Task:**
Есть некий узел,

```
<div class = "child">
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </div>
```

при клике на этот элемент, в `DOM` дереве должно обернуть элемент

**Result:**

```
<div class = "parent">
   <div class = "child">
            Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </div>
</div>
```

**Source:**

```
 let child = document.querySelector("child");
 let parent = document.createElement("div");

child.onclick = function(){

    // 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var child = document.querySelector('.child');

child.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('parent');
  wrapper.innerHTML = child.outerHTML;
  child.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, child);
});
```

```html
<div class="child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

Comment: Не очень хоршо вот так делать `wrapper.innerHTML = child.outerHTML;`. Почему бы не использовать `appendChild`?

Comment: Так не работает же. Не? Кликаю, ничего не происходит. Или я не так что-то делаю?

Comment: @AlexSazonov а где вы видите код, связанный с кликом?)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не вижу, в том-то и дело. Думал, может магия какая... Просто в вопросе явно указано условие `при клике на этот элемент, в DOM дереве должно обернуть элемент`, я и подумал... ))

Comment: @AlexSazonov, обновил.

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще один вариант.

```js
var child = document.querySelector('.child');

child.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const oldParent = child.parentNode;
  var parent = document.createElement('div');
  parent.classList.add('parent');
  oldParent.replaceChild(parent, child);
  parent.appendChild(child);
});
```

```css
.child {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent .child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так придумалось.

```js
let child = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];

child.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("parent").length > 0) return;
  let parent = document.createElement("div");
  parent.classList.add('parent');
  parent.appendChild(child);
  document.body.appendChild(parent);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем примере Вы указали document.body.appendChild(parent)  а вдруг не известно какое количество узлов может ожидать выше , Вы же именно опираетесь на body нет??

Comment: Ну в данном случае на боди, а там уже в каждом конкретном случае по дереву надо идти выше, куда надо вкорячить. Я ж структуры проекта не знаю. Автор попросил идею, как реализовать оборачивание, я своим видением поделился. :) А выше вон @Stepan Kasyanenko вообще правильно сделал. Сразу парент ноду ищет. Плюсую! :)

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, наиболее логичная последовательность действий - это сначала поместить `.parent` перед `.child`, а затем перенести в него `.child`.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.child'); 
el.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div'); 
  wrapper.classList.add('parent'); 
  this.parentElement.insertBefore(wrapper, this); 
  wrapper.appendChild(this); 
}, { once: true });
```

```css
.parent { padding: 0.5rem; border: 1px solid #d44; }
.child { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<div class="child">
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

Comment: пишу тут в целях секретности https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/LvrWMr